# Laravel declare and find composite key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am working with laravel 5.4 and my issue is how to declare a composite key in model. 
My composite key consists of

`A_ID | S_ID`

I have already research some other solutions but they weren't clear enough for me to understand.

and as the

```
model::find
```

Doesn't work with composite key, what would be the work around that?

Comment: Note about the duplicate: Ignore the accepted answer, and check the second answer with a current vote of 58.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this

```
StoreMember::where('user_id',1)->where('store_id',1)->first();
```